# Tornado async decorators where one depends on another

Tags: asynchronous, tornado, tornado-motor

I'm trying to get my head around Tornado. I'm writing a chat application backed by mongodb and I'm using `motor` for non-blocking access to it.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. Create a decorator that uses `motor` to asynchronously pull the user's record from mongo
2. Validate their credentials (username & token)
3. Create another decorator that checks that the user_id retrieved in 1. above is permitted access to the chat room. This requires another asynchronous call to mongo with `motor` to retrieve the 'ChatRoom' record.
4. Subscribe to the chat room if all is OK

I have decorator 1. working (basically taken from http://tornadogists.org/5251927/):

```
def authenticated_async(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    @gen.engine
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.current_user = yield gen.Task(self.get_current_user_async)
        if self.current_user:
            logging.info("User '%s' (%s) successfully authenticated" %
                         (self.current_user['username'],
                          self.current_user['_id']))
            f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(401, "User not authenticated, "
                                             "aborting")
    return wrapper
```

The trouble is that for the second decorator, I need to access `self.current_user`. Because this is set in an asynchronous callback, it's not available when I get into my `validation` decorator (i.e the validation decorator is called before the auth decorator completes).

Is it just not possible for me to use decorators in this way with asynchronous functions? Do I just need to call the validation method inside the above method after making sure that `self.current_user` is True so it's more like a callback?

I'd ideally like to have my methods in my Handler wrapped with both of these decorators so I can reuse them elsewhere, i.e.:

```
class ChatSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    @validate_invitation_access_async
    @authenticated_async
    def open(self, invitation_id):
        # do stuff here...
```

**Update**
In fact, there is no dependency. user_id is provided as a parameter, and that could be used to run both decorators in parallel - one to confirm authentication, the other to see whether the user with that ID is allowed access to the room. The `open()` method would then only proceed if `self.auth_check == True and self.room_check == True`.

Could `open()` ever be called before the async decorators complete though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch the order of the decorators so your `validate_invitation_access_async` wrapper has access to current_user:

```
@authenticated_async
@validate_invitation_access_async
def open(self, invitation_id):
        # do stuff here...
```

Then the wrapper inside `validate_invitation_access_async` is the "f" in `authenticated_async`: it's called after self.current_user is set. Note that you don't need an additional `gen.engine` decorator, all the wrappers are already engines. Your wrapper could be like:

```
def validate_invitation_access_async(f):
    @gen.engine
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ... use Motor to see if user is authorized ...
        # if not, log and redirect. otherwise:
        f(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

You should also update your code to use Tornado 3's gen.coroutine instead of gen.engine: it's much cleaner. But I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I always thought decorators were executed from the innermost to outermost like described here: http://thadeusb.com/weblog/2010/8/23/python_multiple_decorators. Why does yours work?

Comment: Because that post is wrong. If decorators are written like the ones we're discussing, the top one is entered first, and the bottom is entered last. When the innermost function returns, the return value passes back up the stack of decorators, from bottom to top. But in our case we're not returning anything, so it's only the entry phase that matters, not the exit phase.